# How would I make event.target.className check for an image inside of the div named className?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sorry if I worded the title wrong, I didn't know how to say it in short.

My problem is, I have this code:

```
document.addEventListener("click",changeDesc,true);
function changeDesc() {
    if(event.target.className == "item")
    {
        var CurrentItem = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
        var CurrentDescription = CurrentItem.getElementsByClassName("itemdescription")[0].textContent;
        var ItemBox = document.getElementsByClassName("infobox")[0];
        ItemBox.innerHTML = CurrentDescription;
    }
}
```

that checks if the thing the user clicked on is a class called 'item', and if it is, it changes the text contents of a div.

The item is formatted like this:

```
<li class="item" id="iron_sword">
    <img src="1.png" />
    <p class="itemdescription">Description 1</p>
</li>
```

If I click the area that is covered by the 'li' element itself (stretches horizontally fully), it works perfectly.
However, if I try to click the image INSIDE of the li (image 1.png), it doesn't do anything.

This confuses me because the image is inside of the li, but I think I get why it's happening.

But what I don't get is how I should fix this.
Here's a jsfiddle so you can tinker with the code and if you don't understand, maybe you can see what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/c36uwwmr/1/ (Try to click on any area directly to the left or the right of the images, aka the full area of the li. You can see it does what I want it to do, but it doesn't work if I click the images themselves.

NOTE: I'm not using jquery. My javascript is external.

Comment: `document.getElementById(event.target.id);` is pretty pointless. You should just use `event.target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I try to click the image INSIDE of the li (image 1.png), it doesn't do anything.

Of course, not because then the `event.target` is the image element not the list item with the class. If you want to do event delegation, you have to check all the ancestors of the event target. You'll want to do something like

```
function changeDesc() {
    for (var currentItem = event.target
        ;currentItem != event.currentTarget && currentItem != null
        ;currentItem = currentItem.parentElement
    ) {
        if (currentItem.className == "item") { // or currentItem.classList.contains("item")
                                               // or currentItem.matches(".item")
            …
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

([see updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c36uwwmr/5/))

Comment: I tried to use your solution, but it didn't seem to work.

It seems to just make it so nothing happens, even if I click on the li. I also tried to 'rewrite' it myself, but no dice.

Comment: @SnakeBlock Oops, it needs to be `.parentElement` of course

Comment: You can also do `pointer-events:none` on your child element(s) if you don't want to climb up the DOM. https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events